# Prerequisites for polymer

Tags: polymer

What languages should I learn if I want to fully utilize polymer?  I am looking to get into primarily web development and polymer seems quite versatile but I don't know where exactly to begin and google hasn't shown any specific answers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any special requirement per se. Good understanding of Javascript and DOM would help you understand stuff better. If you're a newbie, it's better to start off with the basics before moving to a specialized framework like Polymer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A little bit vague for me.  I understand html and css and some php but polymer looks more like javascript/python which I am not well versed with.  I would like to get a quick start on polymer to be able to stay current with it.

Comment: Polymer is a Javascript library to build reusable components. I has got nothing to do with Python and it's completely a client side framework. You need to have at least a good working knowledge of Javascript to get started. Based on your comments, I'm assuming you don't have any prior experience with JS. So I'd suggest you to take a look at JS first before hopping on to Polymer. Plus Polymer is still in its early stages and would change a lot in the coming months. So it would be wise to invest your time in getting the basics first.